# Android Eclipse - If button isn't pressed within 'x' seconds then

Tags: android, eclipse

Trying to figure out how to do this, basically my App requires a button to be hit and hit multiple times, it counts how many times you hit it and if you don't hit one within a certain space of time it will display a message.

I just can't figure out how to get the 'If button isn't pressed within 'x' seconds then...' part, I've tried `if(imagebutton1.isPressed())` statement but it checks it instantly when the actvity starts, I just want it to check 'X' amount of seconds after the button was last pressed.

ANy help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: You will need a chronometer to achieve this. Google it. If you stll can't do it add comment here. Ill be free in an hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you would need to record the last time the button was pressed 
Then add a updated while statement 
In c++

```
      Int presses;
      Int timelimit; //the seconds between each press (you can use a chronometer but this is simpler but less accurate (and no decimals)
      Int lastpressed; //need chronometer for more accuracy or decimals)
      Int ammountpassed; //time since you pressed it
  If(imagebutton1.isPressed())
      {   
             Bool Started = Yes;
             Presses++;
        While(!imagebutton1.isPressed()&&ammountpassed<TimeLimit)
         {
           Ammountpassed++;
         };
      };
  If (ammountpassed>=timelimit)
     {
         If (presses>=highscore) 
             {
              DisplayMsg " Number of presses" presses; "! New highscore!";
             };
         Else(presses<highscore)
             {
          DisplayMsg "not fast enough! Number of presses" presses; "!"   };
             };

    };
```

You will have to tweak it a bit to fit your needs ("displaymsg" I for think is the actual function so you might have to change that but there's the logic :)
I recommend hand typing this as I belive I may have made a few error but nothing adding a semi colon or 2 won't fix ;)
Hope it helps :) Good Luck :)

Comment: A chronometer is a measure of time , I just used the value time which is wrong , when u understand chronometer use it instead of the time value

Comment: Ok thanks, I've been reading up on Chronometers but I'm done for today so will pickup tommorow, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every time the user hits the button you can post a message on the handler's queue with your text message to be displayed and the appropriate delay time (and remove previous messages). Therefore if the delayed time exceeds without any press the thread will execute the handler's message. Lets say you want to post to the main handler a message to be executed in *delay* number of milliseconds, then in your activity you would need to hold the reference to the handler and create a Runnable where the necessary text message will be displayed:

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(...);
```

In your OnClickListener of the button you would need to execute only:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    mainHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    mainHandler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
}
```